# Test Projects Display as Folder only in VS2008 on 1 machine

Tags: visual-studio-2008, svn, testing, mstest

I have some projects that I created on my laptop, and they work fine there. I have just added them to the Subversion repository on my home PC, and loaded in VS on that PC only to find that the test projects do not display; they just show as a folder icon, and you can't see anything under the root. There is an expand icon next to the folder icon but clicking it does nothing.

There are 2 solutions this has just happened with. The first is a class library, the second an ASP.NET MVC application. They both use MSTest, the first uses Rhino Mocks also, and the second has MVC references etc.

I did previously have VS2008 Standard on the PC, but have now installed Professional.

I did consider that something had gone missing/ got corrupted in the commit/ retrieve from subversion, but looking at the project files etc in notepad it all looks fine.

Another odd thing is that I have 1 other MVC solution which has had the same happen to it (commit to svn from laptop, open on PC), where the test project is working fine. It uses Rhino Mocks again, but NUnit instead of MSTest. I'm therefore wondering if this is something related to MSTest. The reference is to a dll in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies and that looks fine on the PC, and even if there was some problem with the reference you wouldn't expect this behaviour.

Any ideas for what could be causing this?

Comment: I've seen this as well. In my case it also trashed every template on the system so add new file or project failed. It suggested running "devenv.exe /installvstemplates" which had no effect and I needed a reinstall to fix it. Only thing i'd done prior to this was install Expression Studio 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found and fixed the problem, feel silly for posting question now but maybe someone else will find this useful, or can explain the reason for this happening;

Fixed by adding this to the start of the project files;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Which was at the start of the project file that was working, but not the ones that weren't.

Committed to svn and updated on laptop and still works there, so job done. Don't understand why this happened on laptop and worked there, must have been something to do with the way the test projects were created, they were done in various ways through Visual Studio, but I can't remember which were done in which way